# Dynamically generate, search and filter table using AJAX response and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to generate, search and filter a HTML table using AJAX and jQuery.

I am able to generate a complete table making an ajax call to an API (which provides the data for the table) and then take the results and use .append().

e.g.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'SomeURL',
    dataType:'jsonp',           
    success: function(data){

    $.each(data, function(key, value) {

        $("#mytable").append($('<tr>')
        .append($('<td>')
        .append(value.name))
        .append($('<td>')
        .append(value.age))
        <etc>
```

Now that I have generated the table, I am trying to use the .keyup() function in jQuery to filter the results of the table. However to do this I have another API call which I can use. This call will return data specific to my input search query (whereas the initial API call returns the **entire** data set).

e.g.

```
$("#search").keyup(function() {

    var searchVal = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({

        url: 'SomeURL?query=' + searchVal,
        dataType:'jsonp',           
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            <etc>
```

I'm not sure how to properly implement filtering once I have taken the user's search string input and received a response from the API call.

Also, I'm wondering whether the method I'm currently using to dynamically generate the table is appropriate or if there was a better way to implement this?

Comment: We need a bit more information about filtering — which column of the table do you want to apply the filter on? And what kind of data are you receiving from the second API call?

Comment: have you tried jquery-datatables http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side ?

Comment: I would like to filter by gender. The second API call gives me a dataset based on the gender filter. So if searchVal = 'female', I get a dataset containing only female entries. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this out by constructing a HTML table string and populating it with values from the second API call.

I emptied the existing complete table using jQuery before appending the filtered results to it. This allowed me to dynamically filter the table as search queries were typed.

```
$("#search").keyup(function() {

    var searchVal = $(this).val();

    // empty table content here before appending filtered data

    $.ajax({

        url: 'SomeURL?query=' + searchVal,
        dataType:'jsonp',           
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            // construct the table string here
```